# How can I keep alive a connection socket after write from client PHP to server C++

Tags: php, sockets

I'm trying to make a socket connection between a PHP aplication and a C++ aplication, but I don't know why I can't keep alive the connection between those 2 applications after I wrote from PHP. This is my socket-client:

```
$host    = "172.12.10.1";
$port    = '7054';
$factory = new Factory();
$socket = $factory->createClient($host.':'.$port);
echo 'Client connected to ' . $socket->getPeerName() . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL."<br>";
$strSndMsg="TEST";
$socket->write($strSndMsg);
var_dump($socket->read(8192));
$socket->close();
```

So like I said,  after `$socket->write($strSndMsg)` was executed the C++ app show me "Client connect- Cliente disconnect - Test" but I didn't get a response in my $socket->read(8192). Can somebody help me please!?

Comment: You should probably review the specifications of whatever protocol that server is running. Assuming that it's a text-based protocol it's probably either waiting for and EOL sequence [eg: `\n` or `\r\n`] or an actual, valid command.

Comment: And what is your C++ code?

Comment: @RyanVincent I'm using the library "clue/socket-raw" (https://github.com/clue/php-socket-raw) do you know a better option than that library?

Comment: @Sammitch Could you explain me what means "EOL sequence" please? I mean.. Do I have put "\n or \r\n" at the end of my messages to server? or something like that?